# php file fpdf with top banner

Tags: php, dynamic, fpdf, banner

I have a website that has PHP Dynamic Script that generates PDF worksheets through FPDF. Now I like to have a top banner on the generated page. I know that isn't possible if your extention is .pdf, but my question is if that is possible on a .php file that generates a pdf.
An example of a page that needs a top banner is:
http://www.lessucces.nl/images/werkbladgenerator/rekenen/tellen/watismeertot10.php

I hope that is possible. This because most of my visitors use links on other external websites that link directly to a .php file of my website. If I can't do anything I don't have enough benefits out of it.

Hope somebody knows a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could display the pdf in an iframe that sits below you header information

```
 <header> This is my header </header>

 <iframe src="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf",
 id: "pdfRendered" width="100%" height="100%" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0d9cr7r3/

Comment: Thank you @Stacker-flow, but my pdf document has to be only the worksheet that the students use, so no special header there. What I mend was a header with banner above the pdf page, not the pdf worksheet, or maybe a popup that will popup on show.

Comment: @MartinStoel Sorry I miss understood you previously, placing the PDF in an full-sized <iframe> would allow you to still display whatever you want in a header above.